# Excel VBA, ADO connection, return the date if exists, or the previous available date

Tags: vba, excel, ado, adodb

I opened a new ADODB connection, and set a new recordset that have dates in the first field and values in the second field.

- 01/01/2016
- 02/01/2016
- 04/01/2016
- 05/01/2016

So I'm building function `myfunction(mydate)` that should return the maximum available date which is equal or less(earlier) than mydate:

```
myfunction(mydate as date)
Dim CurrentDate as Date

Set rst = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM tbl1 ORDER BY dates;")
CurrentDate = worksheetfunction.INDEX(rst.Fields(0),worksheetfunction.MATCH(CDate(CurrentDate),rst.Fields(0), 1))

myfunction = CurrentDate
end function
```

The results should be

- myfunction("02/01/2016") = 02/01/2016
- myfunction("03/01/2016") = 02/01/2016

This works on excel speadsheet, but it gives an error "Unable to get Match property of the WorksheetFunction". Is there another way to get the result using this Array ?

Comment: You could use a WHERE clause in your SQL? And maybe a TOP?

Comment: The problem is that recordset should be used for several functions, so I can't use WHERE.. This is the short version of my code.

Comment: Right now you are only passing one value (Fields(0) as second parameter of Match where an array of value is expected, that's might be why the complain.

Comment: OK, but '0' means first column, and isn't  `rst.Fields(0) ` an array?

Comment: No, it means first field of current row of the recordset.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! So, I guess the only way is to execute another recordset for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you do multiple recordset:

```
Function myfunction(mydate as date) as date
    Dim CurrentDate as Date
    Set rst = cn.Execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl1 WHERE (dates<=" & Format(mydate, "#mm/dd/yyyy#") & ") ORDER BY tbl1.dates DESC;")
    if not rst.EOF then
        CurrentDate = rst.Fields(0)
    else
        'No record found
    endif
    myfunction = CurrentDate
end function
```

Comment: But I have a question. If I open a connection and than execute the whole recordset, and use filter in function, would this be faster than if I execute data every time ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the recordset find method:

```
rst.movefirst
rst.find "datecolumnname >= " & mydate
If rst.BOF = false then
  myfunction = rst.fields(0)
Else
  Set myfunction = nothing
Endif
```

Comment: but the `Find` method wants ability to move backwards. This gives an error "Rowset does not support scrolling backward", despite I have set the recordset to dynamic mode: `rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic`.